# How to choose one column over another in a join if the column value is NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am using sql server and using ANSI-89 standard.

1. I want to show the transport type name on each of the orderitems along with the item details
2. the transport code can be set at the order or individual orderitem.
3. The transport code on order item precedes the one on order table if its present.
4. If there is no transport code set on Order or OrderItem , i still need to retrieve the orderitem.

transport type is a join with the transport table on transporttypecode. 
the order or orderitem is joined with the transport table on transportcode.

How do I do a conditional join, if that is possible to get the transport type name for each order item, what is the right approach to use here so that I can pick the transport_code on order or order_item accordingly and join with transport table?

```
Order
-----
orderNo (PK)
country NOT NULL
transportCode NULL

OrderItems
----------
OrderNo (PK)
orderItemNo (PK)
transport_code NULL


Transport
---------
trasportcode (PK)
transportname NOT NULL
transporttypecode NOT NULL

transportType
-------------
transporttypecode (PK)
transporttypename NOT NULL
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
Order 
    OrderNo   Country  TransportCode
    1             USA       ST1
    2             ENGLAND       

Order Item
    Order No orderItemNo itemname transportCode
    1            1         cooker    ST2
    1            2         scissor
    2            1         stapler
    2            2         pencil    ST3
    2            3         bottle    

Transport
    transportcode           name        transporttypecode
    ST1                 INS BUTTERFLY           W
    ST2                 LUFTHANSA               A
    ST3                 TRANS SIBERIAN RAIL     RL

TransportType
    Transporttypecode name
    W                 Water
    A                 Air
    RL                Rail
```

**Output**

```
Order No orderItemNo itemname    transportName      transporttypeName
1            1         cooker    LUFTHANSA                Air
1            2         scissor   INS BUTTERFLY           Water 
2            1         stapler
2            2         pencil    TRANS SIBERIAN RAIL     Rail
2            3         bottle
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I have updated the question with sample date and expected output. Also rephrased the query. Please let me know if this is clear?

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [ask] & [mcve]. That includes cut & paste  runnable code including DDL. Show what relevant parts can you calculate. Instead of asking about 'conditional join', whatever you mean by that, clearly describe how the output table (or relevant others) is a function of the input tables. A row (orderNo, ...) is in the result when some values for o.*, oi.*, t.*, ... row (o.orderNo, o.country, ...) is in Order and orderNo=o.orderNo and ...?

Comment: Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn how to use `@` before a non-poster username to notify them of a comment when there is more than one of them.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `coalesce()` in the `on` clause:

```
select oi.*, t.transportName, t.transporttypeName
from orderitems oi join
     orders o
     on oi.ordernum = o.ordernum left join
     transport t
     on t.transportcode = coalesce(oi.transportcode, o.transportcode) left join
     TransportType tt
     on tt.Transporttypecode = t.Transporttypecode;
```

Comment: hI @Gordon I am using ANSI 89 standard, so its a bit old style. Thanks a lot for your solution but can you let me know how I can adapt it to ansi 89 standard. Also it needs to be left join because transport code can be null on order or orderitem tables.

Comment: This is `LEFT JOIN` to Transport as you require.You can use a `CASE` instead of `COALESCE()` if your engine doesn't support it (often times RDBMS's will rewrite COALESCE to CASE under the hood anyway). `CASE WHEN oi.transportcode IS NULL THEN o.transportcode ELSE oi.transportcode END`

Comment: @megan . . . Your question is tagged "sql-server".  I believe this product has supported proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax since it was introduced into the market.  As far as I know, there is no commercial product that does not support `JOIN` syntax, and there hasn't been for over a decade.